# How to create a url redirect from a domain to another using nginx ingress controller and masking the url?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

I have the following problem to solve:

I need to allow clients to use theirs custom domains for our website. I already created a whitelabel subdomain and ask to a client to create a CNAME record on their DNS pointing to it. What i'm trying to accomplish here is that when the client access the CNAME address, my nginx ingress controller recognize the address, redirect to the white label subdomain, keeping the original url using my certificate configured on the ingress.

I have this ingress configured:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 50m
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 50m
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      if ($http_host = clientsubdomain.clientdomain.com)
      {
         rewrite (.*) https://mywhitelabelsubdomain.domain.com$1;
      }
  name: ingress-resource
  namespace: mynamespace
  
spec:
  rules:
  - host: mywhitelabelsubdomain.domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: my-service
          servicePort: 80
        path: /?(.*)
  - host: clientsubdomain.clientdomain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: my-service
          servicePort: 80
        path: /?(.*)
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - mywhitelabelsubdomain.domain.com
    secretName: my-secret
```

But when I hit https://clientsubdomain.clientdomain.com it redirects to my https://mywhitelabelsubdomain.domain.com changing the url on the browser. How can I make this redirect keeping the original url?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: in other words you want to achieve the following:   browser shows "client.domain", at the ame time cert is for "whitelabel.domain", and served by service that is used for "whitelabel". Am I right?

Comment: @Nick yes, you are right!

Comment: I'll play with it and let you know. https://serverfault.com/questions/586586/nginx-redirect-via-proxy-rewrite-and-preserve-url you might want checking this

Comment: @Nick already did. If you're talking about the proxy_pass directive, it's kind tricky to use on a server-snippet block, cause the nginx already translate the -host block with a proxy_pass. In the ingress controller logs you can see erros with the message: Proxy_pass cannot be used here. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you manage to find solution ?

Comment: I wonder did you find a solution?

Comment: I didn't solve the problem that way. It is impossible to call a https domain with the certificate pointing to another domain. What i did was to create another certificate for the original domain that I want to call.

Comment: I have the same dilemma. Has anyone came up with a solution for this problem?